# speed up a file scan crc algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, checksum

I am trying to scan a folder with 1000 files of 1.4 GB in total takes sometimes 10 minutes on lot of computers, which is very unacceptable.
I coded this below and i would like to know how i can speed it up, if its even possible.
Note that files are never over 250MB, hence the buffer.
This code is run against each file in the folder.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(szFilePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (dwSize != -1)
    {
        if (dwSize > 0)
        {
            DWORD dwChecksum = 0;
            DWORD dwReadS = 0;
            DWORD dwReadFar = 0;
            bool bFailed = false;

            if (ReadFile(hFile, pFileBuffer, 250000000, &dwReadS, NULL))
            {
                dwChecksum = CalculateChksum(pFileBuffer, dwReadS);
            }
            else
            {
                bFailed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

DWORD CalculateChksum(BYTE* pData, int len, DWORD CRC)
{
    DWORD  crc = CRC;
    const DWORD* current = (const DWORD*)pData;

    while (len >= 4)
    {
        crc = *current++ + crc;
        len -= 4;
    }

    const BYTE* currentChar = (const BYTE*)current;
    while (len-- > 0)
        crc = *currentChar++ + crc;

    return crc;
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely that the code matters in the measurable performance.  The bulk of the time is in reading the files.  The OS tends to make inefficient methods of file reading more efficient (with various read ahead and caching).  So in a task like this one, it rarely matters much how your code acts.  The most efficient file reading time is still pretty slow and that time dominates everything else.

Comment: If your programm shows lots of disk I/O, then has high CPU load, then again disk I/O, putting the checksum calculation into another thread might help. This will at least double your memory footprint though, because you have to use more than one buffer. And it would only eliminate the periods where there is no disk I/O but CPU load.

Comment: might the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING help?

Comment: Generally stuff like FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING will usually decrease performance UNLESS you know EXACTLY what you do. So effectively I'd just measure the performance (with buffering compared to without). However you probably need to restart your computer between the test runs (to avoid that system internal buffering will affect the measurements).

Comment: If you have control over those files, you may want to consider using an "archive" format like zip or tar then unpack and process the files in memory only. Then you can drastically improve performance (Performance of reading 1 big file is much better than reading lots of small files). However if you don't control the files, you're out of luck

Comment: 1.4GBs in 10 minutes is 2.3 MB/s, that's really a small value... I don't think the I/O by itself is your bottleneck, but you can easily rule it out by just commenting out the invocation of `CalculateChksum()` and measuring the execution time again. Maybe the file scanning part, especially if the files reside on a windows share... just some hints: try to determine where you bottleneck is first of all.

Comment: Why are you even doing this? The disk blocks that comprise the file are protected by a checksum which is far more mathematically robust than your horribly naive algorithm, and you are spreading your 32 bits of sum over far too much data. Once you have your bad sum, what are you going to do with it? Compare it to a later scan so you can take twice as much time to no effect? Finally, requesting 250000000 bytes at a time probably increases the memory access time for no benefit.

Comment: Use multiple threads, each working on a file. That by itself will yield a huge performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is idling when the file is partially read. To speed that up, read 1 MB chunks and decode them on the fly. Pass `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` to `CreateFile` so Windows will know to prefetch the next chunks.

Also, make sure to test with an optimized build. Your function is simple enough that a single thread should keep up with disk I/O, but this might not be the case in debug builds.

BTW, you do know that's not CRC ? Your algorithm fails to catch trivial modifications such as endianness swapping.

Comment: Yes about the CRC, it was an attempt to optimize the scan function. I will test your method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the whole list of files beforehand and create a list. Create a pool of say 20 threads. Let each thread take the next unprocessed file, process it and update the CRC. This should give you a large speedup.

For similar problems I have seen huge improvements. I had a requirement once to open 50K files and then calculate some ACL related content. With 20 threads on an SSD I was able to get this down to 30 seconds. The initial single-threaded mode would take 3 minutes.